# Overriding config file with env variable in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, integration-testing, cypress

I am using this link as a reference to pass configuration to my cypress tests : https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api.html#Switch-between-multiple-configuration-files

My sample config file looks like this:

```
 {
  "env": {
    "country": "US",
    "testenv": "staging",
    "US": {
     "baseUrl" : "somevalue"
    }
}
```

Now I want to override the country value from the command line, I tried using

```
cypress open --env country="Germany"
```

but it still doesn't pickup the value passed in command line and still takes the value from configuration file. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please update your question to show full CLI command you are using to start cypress with these env value override?

Comment: Done. Thank You for the edits.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what happens in your case. Here is the resolved settings when doing just `npx cypress open`

[image]

Now when I run with `$ npx cypress open --env country=Canada` here is the resolved settings tab

[image]

Comment: In my case, i am passing the file via the plugin as recommended in the guide like this: ```module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // accept a configFile value or use development by default
  const file = config.env.configFile || "staging"; return getConfigurationByFile(file);```  ```function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve(".", "cypress/config", `${file}.json`);

  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
}``` - for some reason, it always defaults to the values in the config file. I will try your method now. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and resolved it using the following approach:

I am using following command:

```
npm run dev -- --config video=false
```

This gets converted into following by node:

```
cypress open -C config.json "--config" "video=false"
```

This ONLY works when I don't have the video flag present in my `config.json`. So I can't start with a default value for a parameter that I would like to override.